# Edits by others to my questions and answers

Tags: support

There have been a lot of changes recently and I am bored wandering around trying to find the aisle I want in this supermarket, it is getting as bad as GoDaddy. Is there a map of where things were and where they are now? For example, where have edits to my questions and answers gone?

Comment: `responses`-> `revisions` I think

Comment: @Pekka (too lazy to type everything ;)) - very correct, didn't know about this myself and just found that THREE of my posts were edited! :-D

Answer (score 1):

You will find most of the changes here:
[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

And in particular this [specific post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446) keeps updating.

Add the question to your favorites to read about the changes as soon as they're published. :)

Comment: That is a pretty list, but it is not a map. It is all very well to know that ice cream has been moved to aisle 2, but where is aisle 2? grumble, mutter, grumble, people these days ...

Comment: @Remou sorry but I don't agree with you. Changes are necessary, and all in all they've made really good job here. When you re-decorate your house, do you keep full list/map of what used to be for your guests? No, the guest enjoy the decorations you made and you can guide them around showing them where everything is located. :)

Comment: @Shadow: Well, you also needed Pekka's guidance, didn't you? `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik yes, but the difference is that I'm not so bothered by the changes and actually didn't know such thing ever existed. :P

Comment: In many business, people who complain are useful, they represent all the people who were too polite to complain and just went elsewhere. Changes are not always necessary, and for some time after changes are made, you will find people who have just popped in frustrated by having to take 20 minutes for a 2 minute job. It is all very well if you live with the changes on a day to day basis, but far more disconcerting if you have been away, as I have, or are an irregular visitor, as the majority are, but it is your place, and I will leave it to you to do what you wish.

Comment: @Remou I never said you are not useful, just that I have different opinion than you. I understand what you say and my advice is just ask about anything you miss or can't find - here on Meta you're likely to get speedy response to almost any question you throw about design changes. Last but not least, it's far from being *my* place, or anyone's place.... there is team of moderators/developers who maintain the place and doing regular updates/changes and all the rest is managed by the community. :)